# What do professors do with personal copies of old textbooks?

Tags: books

I've been teaching a few years now and the number of older editions of textbooks is beginning to pile up in my office. There is no policy at my university for disposal of old textbooks. These books were purchase with department funds and it troubles me to throw them away. They content is still relevant as the newer editions are not ground-breaking in material.

My questions are as follows...

1. Please share how you deal with older editions of textbooks?
2. Is there a policy at your institution (if so please share) or do you have a personal way of dealing with this problem (again please share)?

Comment: You might be interested: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123244/what-can-i-do-with-like-new-recent-edition-textbooks-that-im-not-allowed-to-se

Comment: I keep mine, very handy as some NEW versions drop perfectly good practice questions as part of the new version editing process...

Comment: Are there any used bookstores (or even "thrift shops") in your area to which you could denote (or sell cheaply) the books?

Comment: Point of information: Is the faculty/department not supplied with gratis desk-copy textbooks from the publisher? I thought that was customary; maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro That option might be problematic for books purchased with department funds.

Answer (score 6):

At my school the custom seems to be just leaving them in a stack in the hallway next to one's office door. Anyone walking by can peruse through them and take anything they want. At some point the janitorial stuff disposes of the stack as rubbish.

Comment: I've seen this custom too

Comment: I've seen this too, mostly when a professor retires or moves office. Then there can be a respectable pile of books with a note saying "free", and often an email to students in the department (depending on the nature of the books, it might only be sent to graduate students).

Answer (score 2):

At my institution the library of the university accepts donations of books, especially if they are in decent conditions. It seems like the best possible destination for your books since it seems that your institution paid for them, and in this way you'd be "giving them back".

Answer (score 0):

> I've been teaching a few years now and the number of older editions of textbooks is beginning to pile up in my office. [The] content is still relevant as the newer editions are not ground-breaking in material.

Do you need the latest versions? Perhaps reduce the frequencies with which you acquire textbooks.

> There is no policy at my university for disposal of old textbooks.
>   These books were purchase with department funds and it troubles me to
>   throw them away.

Is there a policy for the disposal of university/departmental assets? That might be worth checking. That said, it probably doesn't apply to low value assets such as textbooks.

> Please share how you deal with older editions of textbooks?

1. Donate them to the departmental or university library;
2. Offer them to students, especially those that are struggling financially.

Comment: Eventually older editions are harder to get for students. So after a while the newer edition will be the one used by students. It is very helpful for me as a teacher to have the same edition as the students. So, yes I often need the newest edition.

Comment: @MaartenBuis _older editions are harder to get for students_ that really depends on the material. _It is very helpful for me...to have the same edition as the students_ I don't see why that's "very helpful," perhaps "somewhat useful," but I doubt there is any significant advantage, since---in many instances---much of the material remains the same.

Comment: @user2768 it is useful to have the same version, as students now seem to need precise direction to diagrams or topics ie page 44, diagram on top left. In the past one could suggest find the chapter on XXX and the diagram about YYY and they would...

Comment: @SolarMike I believe spoon feeding students is a disservice.

Comment: @user2768 you may well believe that, but what they demand and what faculty are then **told** to provide is something else...

Comment: @SolarMike I can't believe faculty are told to spend money on numerous textbooks to ensure they have the editions their students have, just to ensure they can provide page references...

Comment: @user2768 Do you teach? Do you have a set course textbook? What happens when version 2 is no longer available and the publisher supplies version 3? You have to go with it...

Comment: @SolarMike _What happens when version 2 is no longer available and the publisher supplies version 3?_ That's irrelevant to me, my students can buy the latest version, I don't need it. Also, copies of version 2 are available in the library, Amazon, ebay, ...

Comment: @user2768 libraries can also dump old versions...

Comment: @SolarMike In my experience they keep textbooks listed in the syllabus.

Comment: @user2768 so that begs the question "do you keep your syllabus up-to-date" ie latest textbooks etc or are you still "chalk & talk"...

Comment: @user2768 Many popular introductory textbooks seem to change problems (or move them around) between editions. If you plan on assigning such problems, the relatively minor expense of getting a new edition is likely justified.

Comment: @Anyon Historically (I'm not sure whether it still holds), publishers used to give instructors text books, so the financial expense can be reduced to zero. Other costs remain though.