Where to donate foreign-language academic books?
After the death of a professor relative, my family on the East Coast has a collection of several hundred Russian-language technical books in physics, math, and hydrology. These were carefully selected works, so the family would like to donate them somewhere where they might be used. How could we find an institution or individual who might be interested in this collection?

Send them to https://1dollarscan.com/ to be digitized, and make them freely available. Although they're unlikely to be of much use to anyone.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123244/what-can-i-do-with-like-new-recent-edition-textbooks-that-im-not-allowed-to-se Closely related, the accepted answer there might be applicable to your case too.

@DimitriVulis By all means go ahead and scan them for your own enjoyment; but making them freely available (i.e., putting the scans online for anyone to download) would very likely violate copyright laws. Publishers are forever fighting a losing battle against their books being made freely available online.

I suppose you don't mean the East Coast of Russia.  (I know the question is tagged [tag:united-states], but for clarity, it wouldn't hurt if the question body would be clear on its own.)

@JanusBahsJacquet That rather depends on when and where the books were published, however. As I understand it, the copyright protection durations were noticeably shorter in the Soviet Union than in the West, which I think is used by the group scanning and uploading titles published by Mir books.

@Anyon Very true. Regardless of copyright law, it also makes a big difference to most publishers whether it’s a book they’re still actively selling, or one that’s been out of print for decades with no chance of ever being reprinted.

In the city where I live in similar situation relatives started asking on social media (and found me to donate me books, that's why I know). May be you can try the same thing: find somebody interested in your area using social media.


a collection of several hundred Russian-language technical books in physics, math, and hydrology

Given these specific fields, I would encourage reaching out to the Niels Bohr Library & Archives at the American Institute of Physics, which is  physically located in College Park, Maryland. Historical physics books are squarely in their wheelhouse, and hydrology topics relevant to geophysics should be relevant too. I'm not sure about mathematics. A fact of relevance here is that they do have a considerable collection of books in Russian. The library is particularly interested in older materials, books with annotations by prominent scientists, and less commonly stored materials such as catalogs and manuals. Their guidelines for donating books can be found here, and guidelines for donating other materials can be found here.

If you are close to the university in which they taught and there are students there from Russia (or who speak Russian), one fairly common solution is to ask another professor to help by leaving some subset (not several hundred at once) in the hallway with a "free" sign on the box. They will disappear.
I'll note that there was a time, during the Cold War, where quite a lot of math was done in, for example, St. Petersburg, and it was somewhat difficult in the West to get access to the ideas. Perhaps you have a few gems in the collection.
You might contact a head librarian at a university library to see if there is any interest.
If there is another Russian scholar there (or at a more nearby place) they might be able to help, especially if they have kept contact with others. I don't know the current state (retired) but I taught a lot of Russian immigrants in the US.
A more general solution, not focused on Russian language books, but very useful even for English or French books is to have a set of scholars finance a shipment of books to some place in, say, Africa, where books are expensive and hard to come by and where students tend to know the language. A local professor where I live did this on his own, collecting books from colleagues and sending them to Kenya, where he was originally from. This, I think, is expensive, as he tried to fill a shipping container.
